# How to throw multiple record failures via kafka BatchListenerFailedException?

Tags: spring, multithreading, asynchronous, spring-kafka

I am collecting the results of parallelly processed records and throwing BatchListenerFailedException with the failed record; my intention is to commit the offset of successful record and throw the failed record for RecoveringBatchErrorHandler for retry.

But whats happening is once BatchListenerFailedException is thrown it exits of the loop and does n't acknowledge the remaining. So I tried placing ack.acknowledge in my called @Async service; but then when a BatchListenerFailedException is thrown on failure everything in that batch is thrown and none acked. Any help is appreciated.

```
for (String futureIndex :resultset) 
            {
                logger.info("The Records Results are "+futureIndex);        

                if (futureIndex.contains("SUCCESS"))
                    {
                    
                    logger.info("***Acknowledging -->"+futureIndex.split("~")[2]);
                    ack.acknowledge();
                    }
                else { 
                    String errorindex=futureIndex.split("~")[2];    
                    throw new KafkaConsumerException("Exception occured in sending json via HTTPS",records.get(Integer.parseInt(errorindex)));
                
                    }
                        
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

With a batch listener, the `Acknowledgment` is for the entire batch, not one record at a time. You should only call `ack()` if the whole batch is successful.

Throwing a `BatchListenerFailedException` with the `RecoveringBatchErrorHandler` will commit the offsets prior to the failed record and re-seek the partitions so the remaining records are redelivered.